# How to get a list of devices or users to which a notification was delivered using Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get a list of all devices or users to which a specific notification was delivered. Is it possible to get that data in Firebase Cloud messaging? If not, then could you recommend any other push notification providers that can help me achieve this?

Really appreciate your help & thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible but it requires some work.

You can enable FCM export to BigQuery in the GCP console. Export will create a "firebase_messaging" dataset and populate it with a scheduler. You'll then need to query it with SQL requests against that dataset.

Note that iOS devices will not export the "delivered" status flag, only Android devices will. This is a known limitation.

An alternative would be to use Google Analytics, but it requires more work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will look into the BigQuery solution.